# SimpleDateFormat parse doesn't work on Date in UTC format from database

Tags: android, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing, android-date, parseexception

I use Parse.com and each ParseObject has date column with Date type in UTC format.

I want to sort those object which I get from query by date. So I'm using SimpleDateFormat and Comparator to compare dates but It throws this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766) 
     Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Dec 06 16:20:00 GMT+01:00 2018" (at offset 0)
```

Code:

```
private fun formatQueryData(unsortedList: ArrayList<ParseObject>){
        unsortedList.sortWith(object : Comparator<ParseObject>{
            var f = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'")
            override fun compare(o1: ParseObject, o2: ParseObject): Int {
                try {
                    return f.parse(o1.getDate("date").toString()).compareTo(f.parse(o2.getDate("date).toString()))
                } catch (e: ParseException) {
                    throw IllegalArgumentException(e)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I can’t get your stacktrace and your code to match. The method/function you show us is `formatQueryData`, but the stacktrace doesn’t mention any error in a method by that name. I might suspect the error happens somewhere else.

Comment: An obvious partial explanation would be that you’ve already got a `Date` object, you convert it into a `String` using `toString` and get `Thu Dec 06 16:20:00 GMT+01:00 2018`, then try to parse this string back to a date specifying the format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'`. However, the string from `toString` is not in that format, so parsing fails. But if you already had a `Date`from the outset, just keep it rather than converting it to string and back.